# Cassandra data modeling: choosing partition key and composite key

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling, datastax-enterprise

I am trying data modeling with Cassandra and I am confused on what should I choose as my partition key and composite key. My table looks like below

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable ( 
id UUID,
A text,
B text,
C text,
D text,
... other columns
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I have introduced an id column in my table and made it as primary key, so that querying with id is faster.

The problem that I am facing is the set of columns (A,B,C,D) uniquely identifies the data, and whenever I perform insertion I want to prevent duplication and searching with the set of column(A,B,C,D) might be expensive since its not part of my primary key.

I am generating the id randomly, one approach that I though was to hash the 4 columns, then it would solve the duplication problem but I skeptical about how the data would be distributed if I start taking the hash for the id.

Other approach that I though of was making (A,B,C,D) as clustering key so that my primary key now looks like `((id), A,B,C,D)` and using the clustering key before insertion to prevent duplication, here I am not sure how efficient the searches are just with the clustering key?
Which of the above approach for data modeling is more suitable or is there any other approach?

Comment: Design your table around how you want to query it, not by how you want to insert it (writes are very very cheap, reads are relatively expensive). You will probably end up with duplication if you want to access data multiple ways and thats Ok.

Comment: I would recommend to take DS220 course on https://academy.datastax.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your primary concern is data integrity (no dupes), you really have no choice but to make (A, B, C, D) your primary key. As for which subset of those columns to choose as partitioning key, there are several considerations. One of them is that for better scalability you want approximately even distribution of your data among partitions. So if D can only have 2 values, one of them used in 99% of rows, don't make D a sole partitioning column. Another consideration is how you want to query the data. If you want to be able to query by subsets of columns -- for example, query by (A, B, C) and (B, C, D), then your partitioning key choice is limited to either B, or C, or (B, C).